# How to display the current tab in HTML?

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am using HTML link attribute

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Click me</a>
```

Here If I click the **"Click me Link"** it is opening a new tab.but it should display the current tab only.

May anyone help me to do this.

Thanks In advance

Comment: Suppress target="_blank" or replace it by target="_self" (cf: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want just leave target blank eg target=""

```
<a href="http://Google.com/" target="">Click me</a>
```

else you can test these out

opens it in the same window it was clicked in

```
<a href="http://webdome.com/" target="_Self">Click me</a>
```

opens it in the paren frame

```
<a href="http://webdome.com/" target="_Parent">Click me</a>
```

For New window or tab

```
<a href="http://webdome.com/" target="_Blank">Click me</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `target="_blank"` attribute/value.

Comment: @jeff..When I click the Click me..The default tab should be "click me tab" but it is showing the google tab

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" target="_self">Click me</a>
```

Comment: ..I need to open both the tabs..but fist should display the "Click me" tab

Comment: @bhai both the tab means i cant understand can you please be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the target attribute from anchor tag if you want to open this link in the same tab .

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Click me</a>
```